# Rendering in Layout and table like alignment without table tag using div only in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
            <li>
                <div class="link">Web Design</div>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="link">Coding</div>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

**css file**

```
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position: absolute;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*Submenu*/

.submenu {
   padding:0px;
  display: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e; }

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color:#c9c7d5;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        var Accordion = function (el, multiple) {
            this.el = el || {};
            this.multiple = multiple || false;


            var links = this.el.find('.link');

            links.on('click', { el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple }, this.dropdown)
        }

        Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function (e) {
            var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

            $next.slideToggle();
            $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

            if (!e.data.multiple) {
                $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
            };
        }

        var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
    });
});
```

The Objectives

**1.** the alignment is not coming correct  ,  currently its like ---  https://ibb.co/fiUOrF
            it should be like ---- https://ibb.co/e5hbBF --- cant use table tag -- divider(the line) between sidebar and the content is important - it should appear --- **this is completed**

**2 .** in the accordian menu - when a submenu is clicked it should stay  selected  , as you see its getting closed after the page loads

Please help me with detailed reply

cant use bootstrap - only css3, jquery and razor syntax

Comment: Hi All . 1st objective of css is complete by padding . but can anyone help with with 2nd objective

Comment: Share via JsFiddle or SO Code editor with updated code.

Comment: hi kumar , it reuires a server side script which i cant give you in jsfiddle . all the codes are given here

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the selected accordion submenu open, you should set the 'multiple' option to true. Change the last line of your javascript to:

```
    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), true);
```

Update:
If you want one of the submenu to be opened on page load, you should add display: block to the ul submenu tag you wanted to be open. For example: `<ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">`

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd5tkg3q/).

Comment: If you want one of the submenu to be opened on page load, you should add display: block to the ul submenu tag you wanted to be open. For example: `<ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">`

Comment: as the page is loading fully ,and we cant use ajax . we have to send the value of submenu from the action method of the controller to make it active.. but many many thanks for the suggestion